# libldap-2.4.so.2: cannot open shared object file

Tags: 22.04

```
scilab-6.1.0 scilab-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libldap-2.4.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
```

scilab-bin of scilab-6.0.2 loads correctly. Is it ubuntu 22.04 problem or scilab problem?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't have `libldap-2.4-2`, it has `libldap-2.5-0`

Answer (score 4):

You can install it via this!

```
sudo wget http://http.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openldap/libldap-2.4-2_2.4.47+dfsg-3+deb10u7_amd64.deb 

sudo apt install ./libldap-2.4-2_2.4.47+dfsg-3+deb10u7_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't have `libldap-2.4-2`, it has `libldap-2.5-0`.

So the software is not supposed to be run on Ubuntu 22.04.

You can try to copy an old library to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`.

Download https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/amd64/libldap-2.4-2/download

open the package with Archive Manager and extract `libldap-2.4.so.2`.

Comment: Thanks! other than that, on kubuntu I had to 
`sudo apt install libgssapi3-heimdal` as prompted from here: http://www.codelobster.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=35179&sid=ca12217d4c2a295d92197a643263873f#p35179
to run the current version of joxi