# How to install ZedFree on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies, archive

I use Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and I want to install ZedFree to open an encrypted ZED archive.

I just get a download link from https://www.zedencrypt.com/download

When the download is completed, I run:

```
sudo dpkg -i ZEDFREE-2022.2.Ubuntu18.04.amd64.deb
```

This fails with the the following error:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of zed-free:
 zed-free depends on libqt5xml5; however:
  Package libqt5xml5 is not installed.
 zed-free depends on libldap-2.4-2; however:
  Package libldap-2.4-2 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package zed-free (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (2.1-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 zed-free
```

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

As mention in [libldap-2.4.so.2: cannot open shared object file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411260/libldap-2-4-so-2-cannot-open-shared-object-file), Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't have libldap-2.4-2.

To resolve the issue you have to repare the broken install first with:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

This will remove the zed-free package.

libldap-2.4-2 needs some dependencies to be installed:

```
sudo apt install libgssapi3-heimdal
```

This might trigger the installation of the following additional packages: `libasn1-8-heimdal libgssapi3-heimdal libhcrypto4-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal libheimntlm0-heimdal libhx509-5-heimdal libkrb5-26-heimdal libroken18-heimdal libwind0-heimdal`

Then download the libldap-2.4-2 package [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/amd64/libldap-2.4-2/download) and install it with:

```
sudo dpkg -i libldap-2.4-2_2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.9_amd64.deb
```

Then install the last missing dependency with:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5xml5
```

Eventually, you can install ZedFree with:

```
sudo dpkg -i ZEDFREE-2022.2.Ubuntu18.04.amd64.deb
```