# post upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 - curl error - libldap_r-2.4.so.2 cannot open shared object file

Tags: 22.04, curl

After upgrading to `Ubuntu 22.04` when I run the **curl** command it's giving this error:

```
/usr/bin/curl: error while loading shared libraries: libldap_r-2.4.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

$ which curl
/usr/bin/curl
```

Before the upgrade, it was working fine.

I removed the curl using apt and then reinstalled it again, but still getting same error. Any idea how to resolve this issue?

with regards,
Saravanan

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `curl --version`. On 22.04, `curl` should depend (via `libcurl4`) on `libldap-2.5-0 (>= 2.5.4)` afaik

Comment: I think the apt cache is outdated and you need to force a full package upgrade. Hence, check if this command works: `sudo apt update ; sudo apt autoremove ; sudo apt clean ; sudo apt-get check ; sudo apt full-upgrade curl libcurl4 --reinstall -y`

Answer (score 0):

In my case it is impossible do get the version running `curl --version` because I got the error described above. But when you uninstall and then install curl again, it shows the version it is installing `curl (7.85.0-1ubuntu0.2)`.

Update: I have found a solution, but it involves compile source code. You can follow this steps:

- compile open-ssl from source following this tutorial - https://linuxtect.com/how-to-install-openssl-libraries-on-ubuntu-debian-mint/
- download curl souce code from github - https://github.com/curl/curl
  and follow instructions from this file - https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/GIT-INFO - obs: run `./configure --with-openssl` instead of `./configure` and after `make` run `sudo make install`

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and found that there is local curl installed apart from the default install from ubuntu.

use `locate libcurl.so`

If found any `libcurl.so` in the `/usr/local/lib` path just delete them.

Once the duplicate libs are removed the curl command works fine

Answer (score 0):

I used a combination of answers to solve the issue:

- To install the missing library:

  [libldap-2.4.so.2: cannot open shared object file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411260/libldap-2-4-so-2-cannot-open-shared-object-file)

  ```
   wget http://http.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openldap/libldap-2.4-2_2.4.47+dfsg-3+deb10u7_amd64.deb 
   sudo apt install ./libldap-2.4-2_2.4.47+dfsg-3+deb10u7_amd64.deb
  ```
- To remove DELL's dca-enabler:

  [Ubuntu 20.04 - Curl: symbol lookup error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1358184/ubuntu-20-04-curl-symbol-lookup-error)

  ```
   sudo apt-get purge --autoremove dca-enabler-packages dca-enabler
  ```